# GridSearchCV results are different to directly applied default model (SVM)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, cross-validation, gridsearchcv

I run a Support Vector Machines model on part of my train set with following result:

```
alg = sk.svm.SVC(probability=True, gamma='auto')
cv_results = model_selection.cross_validate(alg, X_pca, labels, cv =4)
```

[image]

but when I am trying to tune the parameters, with following method:

```
model=sk.svm.SVC()
params = {'C' : [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10],
      'gamma' : [0.1, 1, 'auto'],
      'probability' : [True] 
     }
clf =  GridSearchCV(model, params, cv=2, return_train_score=False).fit(X_pca, labels)
pd.DataFrame(clf.cv_results_).loc[:, ['mean_test_score', 'rank_test_score', 'params']].sort_values(by='rank_test_score')
```

[image]

So not only all results looks scetchy because they are the same. but also in one of the rows I have C:1, gamma:auto and probability: True which is the same parameters as in first table.

I want to also say, that the same logic I am using for the rest of my 15 ML algorithms and only SVM showed this kind of weird behavior. Wondering that maybe I have some stupid mistake in how I create X_pca and labels data table, I copied code from other algorithm and just replaced second code but it gave the same results.

Can you spot something wrong?

Comment: one issue i see is the a 4 fold cross validation in SVM (1st) and 2 fold cross validation in grid search SVM (2nd).

Comment: I did also 4 fold previously on SVM, but haven't saved the result so now I did just 2-fold to print the results faster. The scores were rougly the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be due to the data, as this code:

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X_pca = np.random.rand(100, 2)
labels = X_pca[:, 0] + X_pca[:, 1] > 0.5

model = svm.SVC()
params = {'C' : [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10],
      'gamma' : [0., 0.1, 1, 'auto'],
      'probability' : [True] 
     }
clf =  GridSearchCV(model, params, cv=2, return_train_score=False)
clf.fit(X_pca, labels)

print(pd.DataFrame(clf.cv_results_).loc[:, ['mean_test_score', 'rank_test_score']] \
        .sort_values(by='rank_test_score'))
```

gives better output:

```
    mean_test_score  rank_test_score
10             1.00                1
13             1.00                1
14             1.00                1
15             1.00                1
11             0.95                5
0              0.83                6
1              0.83                6
2              0.83                6
3              0.83                6
4              0.83                6
5              0.83                6
6              0.83                6
7              0.83                6
8              0.83                6
9              0.83                6
12             0.83                6
```

(consider the fact that the results will depend on the seed of the `rand` function, but with other seeds they are similar and the mean test score changes using different values of the parameters.

Comment: I understand that. It looks that my code works on any example besides my data.. 
However, weird is that I am using a loop to apply different algorithms on the same data and ONLY SVC gives some wrong results. All other methods are correct. I wonder if this is algorithm specific problem that I shouldn't apply it on that particular set of data.

Comment: What kind of data is it?

Comment: Can you share it?

Comment: Originally data comes from here: https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/data

Comment: I've also made public my script: https://www.kaggle.com/panpluto/gridsearch-svc/code

It's slightly different to above because I was trying different things to make it work. Like wrapping SVC in OnevsOneClassifier